# How can "toast" (react-toastify) be initialized without launch it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, alert, react-toastify

I need your help. I want to initialized a Toast instance with React.userRef, but without launch it, because I want to use that Ref Id to update any Toast type, and I don't know which Toast type (info, error, success) happens first.

For example:

```js
const alertToast = React.useRef(null)
alertToast.current = toast('')

  const infoAlert = (message) =>
    toast.update(alertToast.current, {
      render: message,
      type: toast.TYPE.INFO,
      autoClose: 1500,
    })
  const successAlert = () =>
    toast.update(alertToast.current, {
      render: 'Success!!',
      type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
      autoClose: 2500,
    })
  const errorAlert = (code, message) =>
    toast.update(alertToast.current, {
      render: `Error with code: ${code} and message: ${message}`,
      type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
      autoClose: false,
    })
```

But the line `alertToast.current = toast('')` always launch the Toast

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same, so I came up with initializing an invisible toast, and make it visible in any other state:

```css
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Use the CSS visibility classes:

```js
const alertToast = React.useRef(null)
alertToast.current = toast('', {className: "invisible"})

  const infoAlert = (message) =>
    toast.update(alertToast.current, {
      render: message,
      type: toast.TYPE.INFO,
      autoClose: 1500,
      className: "visible",
    })
  const successAlert = () =>
    toast.update(alertToast.current, {
      render: 'Success!!',
      type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
      autoClose: 2500,
      className: "visible",
    })
  const errorAlert = (code, message) =>
    toast.update(alertToast.current, {
      render: `Error with code: ${code} and message: ${message}`,
      type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
      autoClose: false,
      className: "visible",
    })
```